# NullPointer exception in a Spring Rest Controller test - Java

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I have the following `Rest Controller` and unit test in Spring-Boot 1.4:

### HealthChecker controller:

```
@RestController
public class HealthCheckerController {

   @Autowired
   private InstanceRepository instanceRepository;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/healthchecker", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public List<Instance> findAll() {
       return this.instanceRepository.findAll();
   }
```

### HealthCheckerControllerTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HealthCheckerControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private InstanceRepository instanceRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HealthCheckerController()).build();

        this.instanceRepository.deleteAll();
        Instance first = new Instance("10.20.30.40", "ami-xxxxxxxx");
        Instance second = new Instance("10.20.30.41", "ami-xxxxxxxx");
        this.instanceRepository.save(first);
        this.instanceRepository.save(second);

        for (Instance instance : this.instanceRepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(instance);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testHealthChecker() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/healthchecker")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].ipaddress", is("10.20.30.40")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].ami", is("ami-xxxxxxxx")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].ipaddress", is("10.20.30.41")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].ami", is("ami-xxxxxxxx")));
    }
}
```

However, when I execute the unit tests, it's giving me the following error:

```
Tests run: 21, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 19.83 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
testHealthChecker on testHealthChecker(cloudos.HealthCheckerControllerTest)(cloudos.HealthCheckerControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.193 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cloudos.HealthCheckerController.findAll(HealthCheckerController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at cloudos.HealthCheckerControllerTest.testHealthChecker(HealthCheckerControllerTest.java:48)
```

Accessing that from the UI works just fine:

```
[{"ipaddress":"10.20.30.40","ami":"ami-xxxxxxxx"},{"ipaddress":"10.20.30.41","ami":"ami-xxxxxxxx"}]
```

I understand the problem is that `private InstanceRepository instanceRepository` is not being initialized in the `unit test`, so when it's accessed inside the `HealthCheckerController` it's null, however that's not the purpose of `@Autowired`? 
How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` you need to manually setup your controller object (it's rather for unit testing)

If you want to use full Spring context (with all `@Autowired` fields available) you will need to use `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup`

This should work:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HealthCheckerControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private InstanceRepository instanceRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

        this.instanceRepository.deleteAll();
        Instance first = new Instance("10.20.30.40", "ami-xxxxxxxx");
        Instance second = new Instance("10.20.30.41", "ami-xxxxxxxx");
        this.instanceRepository.save(first);
        this.instanceRepository.save(second);

        for (Instance instance : this.instanceRepository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(instance);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testHealthChecker() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/healthchecker")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].ipaddress", is("10.20.30.40")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].ami", is("ami-xxxxxxxx")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].ipaddress", is("10.20.30.41")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].ami", is("ami-xxxxxxxx")));
    }
}
```

You could eventually try to add constructor to your controller and manually inject existing repository to newly created controller:

```
@RestController
public class HealthCheckerController {

    @Autowired
    private InstanceRepository instanceRepository;

    public HealthCheckerController(InstanceRepository instanceRepository) {
        this.instanceRepository = instanceRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/healthchecker", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Instance> findAll() {
        return this.instanceRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

and your mvc configuration should look like this:

```
mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HealthCheckerController(instanceRepository)).build();
```